# How to sum cells that are in hexadecimal format

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

**First of all, read 32, 1023 with the 0x32 and 0x1023 to identify that it is a hexadecimal number.**

When we only have numbers the sum is done with decimals and it seems to work. The problem is that in the hexadecimal representation we have values from A to F. So the '=sum()' function is not able to sum cells with letters.

There are two ways I managed to do it:

- create a line below that converts from HEX -> DEC, I do the sum of the values in DEC and then in the checksum line I do the conversion from DEC -> HEX
- as shown in the image, I'm doing the explicit sum of the values converted to decimal and then, in the outermost part, the conversion to HEX and I use the parameter [signed digits] = 8, to represent 4 bytes

[image: manual selection cells]

---

I would like to know how to apply the feature with the following logic:

**-> for each cell in that range (A2:C2) convert to decimal before doing the sum and give me the result in hexadecimal, with 8 signed digits**

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). It is unclear why you refer to converting the numbers using rigid logic. Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)? Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 1):

Use `hex2dec()` and `dec2hex()`, like this:

`=right( "00000000" & dec2hex( hex2dec(A2) + hex2dec(B2) + hex2dec(C2) ), 8 )`